# Include images in excel from a folder

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I need to add the images from a windows folder to the excel sheet such that each image is placed in front of the row entry containing the name of the file.

Something like this- (the name of the file is same as the id column entry in that row)
[image]

What kind of code/language could i use to do this?

I also have this database in Mysql, is it possible to include images in excel using php.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes you can use PHP, but why not use VBA that runs inside Excel and has a superior debug feature?

Comment: you can use phpExcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you are including your phpExcel library in your project ,

```
include 'PHPExcel.php';
// you  create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
// Set properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Yassine CHABLI");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Yassine CHABLI");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("make whatever you want");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("whatever you want");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("including images test (example)");
// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('image example');

$Image = imagecreatefromjpeg('yassine.jpg');

$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($Image);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

For more information , visit the link bellow:

https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel

> notice:  That will create an “xlsx” formatted file because it uses
>   2007 excel classes.  if you want “xls” format just try with 2005 class
>   and do not forget to change the file format to “xls” while using 2005.

Comment: This is not able to insert more than 50 images of around 20KB each. Any solution?

Comment: I understood, memory issue. Solved by ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

Comment: exactly , it's about memory php , if you are trying to do that for a lot of elements , try to make your use code best practices for optimisation .